# Unexpected size of select element inside a particular bootstrap input-group

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

My goal is very simple:

- to have an input-group with inside an input-group-addon, a select, another input-group-addon and a text input
- to have the select and the text input of the same width

Please refer to this JSFiddle showing the problem:
https://jsfiddle.net/yhv5bj0b/

- An input-group-addon and select by themselves, results in the select using all the remaining space [OK - makes sense]
- An input-group-addon, followed by a select, followed by another input-group-addon, followed by another select, results in the two selects splitting the remaining space 50-50 [OK - makes sense]
- An input-group-addon, followed by a select, followed by another input-group-addon, followed by a text input, results in the select and the text input having different widths, the select is always smaller [BAD - can't understand why]

I originally posted this question here as a bug report:
https://github.com/silviomoreto/bootstrap-select/issues/1470

..because I'm a bootstrap-select user. However, the nice folks at bootstrap-select proved to me that this not a bootstrap-select issue at all. They showed to me that removing their class, the issue persists. Hence why my updated fiddle used for asking this question here on stackoverflow does not use the class 'selectpicker'. I have also removed the submit button at the end of the row, which you can see in the old fiddle mentioned in that github page. So I think I've narrowed down the problem to the minimum components needed to reproduce the issue.

Is this a bug in bootstrap?

Thanks a lot for looking, and I hope one of you can help.

```
<div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-addon">Test1</span>
  <select class='form-control'>
    <option>one</option>
    <option>two</option>
  </select>
</div>
<br>
<br>
<div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-addon">Test2</span>
  <select class='form-control'>
    <option>one</option>
    <option>two</option>
  </select>
  <span class="input-group-addon">Test3</span>
  <select class='form-control'>
    <option>one</option>
    <option>two</option>
  </select>
</div>
<br>
<br>
<div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-addon">Test4</span>
  <select class='form-control'>
    <option>one</option>
    <option>two</option>
  </select>
  <span class="input-group-addon">Test5</span>
  <input type='text' class='form-control'>
</div>
```

Comment: See the [Docs](https://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups): Multiple controls inside a single input-group is not supported and avoiding the use of select inputs with input-groups is suggested as well.

Comment: Thanks vanburen, I had missed that. Apparently it's the same in bootstrap v4 (both the rules and the issue).

Comment: No solution to make the site display as I need? (despite what bootstrap may officially support) :P